# Change table header colour using htmlTable

Tags: html, r

I've been having some issues with changing the thead background colour using the htmlTable package in R. By playing around with the css.cell options I was able to change the colour of part of the table header but not all (run code snippet).

```
require(htmlTable)
mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol=5)

htmlTable(mat,cgroup = c("","Rank",""),n.cgroup = c(1,3,1),
      header = LETTERS[1:5],
      css.cell = rbind(rep("background: lightgrey;", 
                           times=ncol(mat)),
                       matrix("", ncol=ncol(mat), nrow=nrow(mat))))

# Not Run
# x = htmlTable(mat,cgroup = c("","Rank",""),n.cgroup = c(1,3,1),
#               header = LETTERS[1:5],
#               css.cell = rbind(rep("background: lightgrey;", 
#                                times=ncol(mat)),
#                                matrix("", ncol=ncol(mat), nrow=nrow(mat))))
# get the output
# as.character(x)
```

The output from the code produces the following

```html
<table class='gmisc_table' style='border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;'>\n
  <thead>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th colspan='1' style='font-weight: 900; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'></th>
      <th style='border-top: 2px solid grey;; border-bottom: hidden;'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th colspan='3' style='font-weight: 900; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>Rank</th>
      <th style='border-top: 2px solid grey;; border-bottom: hidden;'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th colspan='1' style='font-weight: 900; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'></th>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th style='background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>A</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th style='background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>B</th>\n
      <th style='background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>C</th>\n
      <th style='background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>D</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th style='background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>E</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n
  <tbody>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>1</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>5</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>9</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>13</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>17</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>2</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>6</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>10</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>14</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>18</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>3</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>7</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>11</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>15</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>19</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>4</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>8</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>12</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>16</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>20</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>
```

Obviously the "\n" output is annoying, but easily manageable. But does anyone have any ideas on how to control the background colour in the table header directly from R?

I know I can adjust the thead style manually by adding the following to the html output: style="background-color: lightgrey;", but it would be very nice if I could just get the desired output directly from R.

Here is my desired table output, when I manually change the background-color in thead:

```html
<table class='gmisc_table' style='border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;'>\n
  <thead style="background-color: lightgrey;">\n
    <tr>\n
      <th colspan='1' style='font-weight: 900; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'></th>
      <th style='border-top: 2px solid grey;; border-bottom: hidden;'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th colspan='3' style='font-weight: 900; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>Rank</th>
      <th style='border-top: 2px solid grey;; border-bottom: hidden;'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th colspan='1' style='font-weight: 900; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'></th>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>A</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>B</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>C</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>D</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</th>\n
      <th style='border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;'>E</th>\n</tr>\n</thead>\n
  <tbody>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>1</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>5</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>9</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>13</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>17</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>2</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>6</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>10</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>14</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>18</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>3</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>7</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>11</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>15</td>\n
      <td style='' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='text-align: center;'>19</td>\n</tr>\n
    <tr>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>4</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>8</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>12</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>16</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey;' colspan='1'>&nbsp;</td>\n
      <td style='border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;'>20</td>\n</tr>\n</tbody>\n</table>
```

Added bonus, if anyone knows how to get rid of the "\n" output that would also be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to consider `tableHTML` for this one, because it adds full control over CSS. `tableHTML` uses the pipe operator to chain commands.

Using your data:

```
library(tableHTML)
mat %>%
 as.data.frame() %>%
 #tableHTML is the main function that creates the html table
 tableHTML(border = 0, rownames = FALSE, 
           second_header = list(c(1, 3, 1), c('', 'Rank', ''))) %>%
 #the add_css family of functions add CSS to the corresponding
 #parts of the table
 add_css_thead(list(c('background-color'), c('lightgrey'))) %>%
 add_css_table(list(c('text-align'), c('center'))) %>%
 add_css_row(css = list('border-top', '2px solid black'), rows = 1) %>%
 add_css_row(css = list('border-bottom', '1px solid black'), rows = 2) %>%
 add_css_row(css = list('border-bottom', '2px solid black'), rows = 6) %>%
 add_css_second_header(css = list('border-bottom', '1px solid black'), second_headers = 2)
```

Which would result in the table you want, but without needing to use a hack to modify tablehtml or any other package (or needing to manually deal with the `/n`s):

[image]

You can still modify it further if you wish. There is also an online tutorial [here](https://lyzander.github.io/tableHTML/) if you are interested.

Comment: The tutorial was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

I am not very familiar with `htmlTable` in R, but here is an overkill solution using the `XML` package to manipulate the output of `htmlTable`.

```
require(htmlTable)
mat <- matrix(1:20, ncol=5)

tab <- htmlTable(mat,cgroup = c("","Rank",""),n.cgroup = c(1,3,1),
      header = LETTERS[1:5],
      css.cell = rbind(rep("background: lightgrey;", 
                           times=ncol(mat)),
                       matrix("", ncol=ncol(mat), nrow=nrow(mat))))


library(XML)

# Parse the HTML table and add the background color attribute
doc <- htmlParse(tab)
addAttributes(doc[['//thead']], 'style' = "background-color: lightgrey;")

# Convert HTML DOM object to string
html_str <- toString.XMLNode(doc)

# Remove line escapes, as requested
html_str <- gsub('\\\n', '', html_str)

# Remove the DOCTYPE included by htmlParse()
html_str <- gsub('<!DOCTYPE[^>]*>', '', html_str)

cat(html_str)
```

It outputs an HTML string that creates the desired table:

```html
<html><body><table class="gmisc_table" style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;"><thead style="background-color: lightgrey;"><tr><th colspan="1" style="font-weight: 900; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;"></th><th style="border-top: 2px solid grey;; border-bottom: hidden;"> </th><th colspan="3" style="font-weight: 900; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;">Rank</th><th style="border-top: 2px solid grey;; border-bottom: hidden;"> </th><th colspan="1" style="font-weight: 900; border-top: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;"></th></tr><tr><th style="background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;">A</th><th style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;" colspan="1"> </th><th style="background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;">B</th><th style="background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;">C</th><th style="background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;">D</th><th style="border-bottom: 1px solid grey;" colspan="1"> </th><th style="background: lightgrey; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-align: center;">E</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td style="text-align: center;">1</td><td style="" colspan="1"> </td><td style="text-align: center;">5</td><td style="text-align: center;">9</td><td style="text-align: center;">13</td><td style="" colspan="1"> </td><td style="text-align: center;">17</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;">2</td><td style="" colspan="1"> </td><td style="text-align: center;">6</td><td style="text-align: center;">10</td><td style="text-align: center;">14</td><td style="" colspan="1"> </td><td style="text-align: center;">18</td></tr><tr><td style="text-align: center;">3</td><td style="" colspan="1"> </td><td style="text-align: center;">7</td><td style="text-align: center;">11</td><td style="text-align: center;">15</td><td style="" colspan="1"> </td><td style="text-align: center;">19</td></tr><tr><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;">4</td><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey;" colspan="1"> </td><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;">8</td><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;">12</td><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;">16</td><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey;" colspan="1"> </td><td style="border-bottom: 2px solid grey; text-align: center;">20</td></tr></tbody></table></body></html>
```